# How to get data from REST API over self-hosted integration runtime on Synapse Analytics?

Tags: python, azure, rest, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

In my company I got access to a data source via a REST API which can only be accessed from within the company network. When I run my code for testing on my pc, it works as expected. However, I want to run the code on Synapse Analytics which is not internal because it is in Azure. So the code won't work. We got a self-hosted integration runtime for our Synapse Analytics workspace to fix this issue. I couldn't find a documentaion or code snippet to adjust my code.

What do I need to add to my code to make it work?

```
import requests
import base64

# User und Password
username = "user"
password = "pw"

# URL
url = "https://test.server.com/gate/pull/"

# Auth
auth_string = f"{username}:{password}"
auth_header = f"Basic {base64.b64encode(auth_string.encode()).decode()}"

headers = {
    "Authorization": auth_header,
    "Content-Type": "application/json" 
}

# GET
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

json_data = req.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

So for running ur code in Synapse Analytics with a self-hosted integration runtime, guess you need to make a couple of adjustments. First,  switch to Kerberos authentication, it's often used in enterprise setups. Also, make sure you have the requests_kerberos package installed in Synapse.

updated code below

```html
import requests
from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth  # Don't forget to import HTTPKerberosAuth

# URL
url = "https://test.server.com/gate/pull/"

# Use HTTPKerberosAuth for authentication with the self-hosted integration runtime
auth = HTTPKerberosAuth()

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json" 
}

# GET
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=auth)

# Check the response status
if req.status_code == 200:
    json_data = req.json()
    # Process the JSON data as needed
else:
    print(f"Error: {req.status_code} - {req.text}")
```

Hope this he;ps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it doesn't work. The API needs a specific authentication with user and password. I think I need to send the API request via the IR but don't know how.